# php script outputs itself

Tags: php

after submitting a form my php script outputs its code.
sometimes not all of it.

Comment: If you're able to attach the script that'd probably be helpful!

Comment: your <?php ?> tags are in place?

Comment: Maybe your server does not support php?

Comment: It can be that you're using short tags (<? instead of <?php) and this kind of tags is disabled in php.ini

Comment: short_open_tag = On in php.ini
i'm using denwer local server
my script is just calculating simple vars end requiring output html.
there are some tags <? there

Answer (score 4):

Using short tags in PHP is **not** recommended coding style. Here's what I suggest:

1. Go through your PHP scripts **now** and **replace ALL of your `<?` short tags with `<?php`**.
2. If that doesn't work, come back here and post your full script.

Without full information, Rafael's tag suggestion is the best by far.